# Добавление CardView

Tags: java, android

Пытаюсь сделать карточку в андроид...
Добавил библиотеку `android-support-v7-cardview`, начинаю писать

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_width="370dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    card_view:cardElevation="5dp" >

     <RelativeLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/eor"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp" >

          <ImageView
               android:layout_width="50dp"
               android:layout_height="50dp"
               android:background="@drawable/koko"
               android:id="@+id/imageView25"
               android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
               android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
               android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" 
               android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"/>

       </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Вылетает ошибка, что не может инициализировать класс `CardView`. Захожу в класс и вижу, что там ошибка с `import android.support.v7.widget.R;`

> could not resolve symbol R

В этом пакете такого класса просто нет. Поискал в гугле, ничего не нашел, обращаюсь сюда.

Answer (score 1):

1) Проверьте последняя ли у вас версия support-lib стоит и подключена ли она к проекту.

2) В либах supporе-v7 и CardView проверьте поставлена ли в

> Project-Properties-android-project build target

максимальная версия андроид (5.1.1)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: насчет первого пункта да, подключена...а насчет второго, я слегка не понимаю, как это сделать..)

Comment: Правой кнопкой на проекте - Properties. Вторым пунктом в левом списке должен быть Android. Там, справа, будет список. Картинку в ответ добавил.

Comment: я эклипсом пока не пользуюсь, у меня Intellij idea 14.1

Comment: Принцип должен быть тот же. Поройтесь в настройках проекта.

Answer (score 0):

Вот Вам алгоритм действий. Решил представить ответ в привычном для нас виде :-)
Надеюсь, оцените.

1. Удалите все данные, которые Вы добавили для `CardView`.
2. Запустите проект.

Если работает.

- Открываете `build.gradle` файл, который лежит в папке `app`;
- Ищете `dependencies`;
- Дописываете следующую строку `compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.2.0'`;
- Жмете вверху на `Sync gradle`;
- Используете `CardView` по назначению;

Если нет.

- Проверяете свой проект на ошибки;

Comment: спасибо большое;),1) но мне это уже месяц как не нужно 2)я пользуюсь ant'ом

Comment: @DenShDen, не за что)) Я гуглил свой вопрос по CardView и наткнулся на Ваш, решил помочь ;-)

Comment: а у вас какой вопрос? Ссылку дайте, может, тоже помогу.. Полная взаимопомощь:D

Comment: @DenShDen, [ссылка]: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/437519/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%83-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-cardview-%D0%BD%D0%B0-api-16-android-4

Answer (score 0):

У Вас библиотека `android-support-v7-appcompact` подключена к проекту?

Если нет, то подключите ее через `Build Path->Configure BuildPath->Add External JARs`.

Comment: konstantin, подключена..). Я так понимаю, это intellij idea глючит.. Потому что пробовал в android studio, там все работает