# Не могу создать тень для CardView на API 16 (Android 4)

Tags: android, android-sdk, android-widgets

У виджета CardView есть параметр `setElevation(4f)`, который работает на `API >= 21`. Для `API < 21` есть `cardView.setCardElevation(4f)`, но он не работает.

```
CardView cardView = new CardView(getActivity());
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
cardView.setElevation(4f);
} else {
cardView.setCardElevation(40f);
}
```

Я не так вызываю или все таки нужно руками создавать новый View, красить его в градиент, и потом `cardView.addView(myGradienShadow);` как тень ?

Comment: Может, просто создать view с cardview на борту, присвоить ему id, а потом уже в коде его находить и тень делать?:D

Comment: @DenShDen, дело в том, что я в цикле создаю `cardView` и наполняю его там же. В разметке только `LinearLayout`, в который все потом через `addView` добавляется. Делал раньше через LinearLayout, к которому добавлял View с градиентом цвета заливки LinearLayout. Но получалась тень не очень то и правдоподобная. Решил полезть в тему `cardView`, а тут проблема с elevation.

Comment: Принципиально задавать в коде? можешь в xml выставить атрибут card_view:cardElevation="". Но только компонент брать из библиотеки поддержки, как "android.support.v7.widget.CardView"

Comment: @Werder, да. В цикле постоянно создается разное количество этих карточек.

Comment: @web_alex для 17 и выше работает?

Comment: @anber, я не пробовал для 17 версии. У меня смартфон с 16 API. А эмулятор Genymotion вылетает.